# IOS 7+ Custom DateTimePicker Time Range

Tags: ios, iphone, datepicker

I wonder if there is a way to custom a datepicker's time range?

[image]

How can I remove minute column and leave only 9 and 5 in hour column? is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should considere to use this cocoapod:
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/dvdatepickertableviewcell

or this webpage:
http://blog.deeplink.me/post/81386967477/how-to-easily-customize-uidatepicker-for-ios

and try to custom it as you want.

Answer (score 0):

For UIDatepicker it is not possible to remove the minutes column or only to show 9 and 5 hour in hour column.

> UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime:
>   The date picker displays dates (as unified day of the week, month, and day of the month values) plus hours, minutes, and (optionally) an AM/PM designation. The exact order and format of these items depends on the locale set. An example of this mode is [ Wed Nov 15 | 6 | 53 | PM ].

You need to use custom datepicker for that,you may consider to look at this link for custom picker https://github.com/mwermuth/MWDatePicker
  for MWDatePicker first date were invisible but changing the font color like this [datePicker setFontColor:[UIColor blueColor]]; in viewdidLoad in MWViewController.m make them visible.And then modifying the method fillWithCalendar in MWDatePicker.m like this

```
- (void)fillWithCalendar{
    minutes = @[@""];

    hours = @[@"05",@"09"];
   ////others coding

}
```

i think would give you desired output.